# Mouse move and click in C / linux X11

Tags: c, linux, x11

I need to move pointer and perform a click. It is moving ok but the click are not working, can anyone see what I'm missing? Code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

     Display *dpy;
     Window root_window;

     dpy = XOpenDisplay(0);

     root_window = XRootWindow(dpy, 0);
     XSelectInput(dpy, root_window, KeyReleaseMask);
     XWarpPointer(dpy, None, root_window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 180, 500);

     XGrabPointer(dpy, root_window, True, ButtonPressMask, GrabModeAsync,GrabModeAsync, None, None, CurrentTime);

     XFlush(dpy);

    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8775348/4454124

Comment: XGrabPOinter does not perform click, as suggested above best way is to use XTest extension